# building exchange Order Book chart

Tags: algorithm, algorithmic-trading

It's about selling and buying marketplace (i.e mtgox)
So we have a book of orders people ever set:

```
[
    {price:20,kind:BID},
    {price:21,kind:BID},
    ....
    {price:900,kind:BID},
    {price:898,kind:ASK},
    ...
    {price:900,kind:ASK},
]
```

And the goal is to build good order book chart, such as this one here:

[image]

By figuring out column step size and columns count to each side from the middle.

We don't need to display columns for some out-of-market orders like the those in the beginning of dataset.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you simply want to draw a graph similar to the one provided? Which part are you having trouble with? Do you have a language in mind? Maybe some code or pseudo-code to show us?

Comment: @dukeling, the problem is that the chart itself has limited space. Currently if you will put a Bid order to buy at rate 20, it will not affect the left part of chart. Such kind of orders are not displayed o n it, only those which are closer to market edge. So column interval selected in proper way and without human help. For eample, if market will go up then interval from 32 can be 50 and vice versa.  The problem is to select right interval.